# pyodbc unkown encoding error when impersonating user using win32 security

Tags: python, winapi, pyodbc

I'm trying to use the example from https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch07s14.html to connect to a database that another account on my network has access to. The error I'm given is:

r'DSN=Test'

LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-16le

```
import win32security, win32con

class Impersonate:
    def _ _init_ _(self, login, password):
        self.domain = 'bedrock'
        self.login = login
        self.password = password

    def logon(self):
        self.handle = win32security.LogonUser(self.login, self.domain,
            self.password, win32con.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
            win32con.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
        win32security.ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(self.handle)

    def logoff(self):
        win32security.RevertToSelf(  ) # terminates impersonation
        self.handle.Close(  ) # guarantees cleanup

if __name__=='__main__':
    a = Impersonate('barney', 'bambam')

    try:
        a.logon() # become the user
        try:
            # Do whatever you need to do, e.g.,:
            print win32api.GetUserName() # show you're someone else
            cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
                r'DSN=Test;'
            )
        finally:
            a.logoff() # Ensure return-to-normal no matter what
    except:
        print 'Exception:', sys.exc_type, sys.exc_value
```

Comment: idk how relevant this is to the error, but do you really need the `;` in `'DSN=Test;'`? Also, see [docs here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Module#datasources)

Comment: Where does the code fail?

Comment: And you remove both of the `try` blocks, as these are likely suppressing the actual error that is occurring. Using a bare `except` clause is normally a bad idea; you'll want to trap only the specific error you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Patrick, the documentation helped, here was my solution:

```
cnxn =  pyodbc.connect(
    r'DSN=HR;',encoding = 'utf-8',autocommit = True #To set the encoding for the connection
        ) 
cnxn.setencoding(encoding = 'utf-8') #To set the encoding for any queries
```